# Absolute continuity of convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, absolute-continuity

Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. A convex function is absolutely continuous on each closed subinterval of $(a,b)$. Also, the right and left-hand derivatives exist at each point of $(a,b)$, and are equal to each other except on a countable set.

My question is, if a convex function is defined as $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, is the function now absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ ? Also, what can we say about the right and left hand derivatives on $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2):

A convex function may be discontinuous at the endpoints of its domain.

Consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x = a \\
0 & a < x < b \\
1 & x = b
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Quick question: Does continuity imply absolute continuity?

Comment: @superhulk No. But the reverse is true: absolute continuity implies continuity.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See e.g. [continuous but not absolutely continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700931/continuous-but-not-absolutely-continuous-function) for examples of functions that are continuous but not absolutely continuous.